# SQL Query Group by Count and Left Join Tables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

i need your help! I got some simple SQL skills, but this query kills me...

My Tables

[image]

Now i want the TOP5 WorkTimes on the Equipment (What Equipment got the longest WorkTime).

I want this OUTPUT:

[image]

MY Query:

```
SELECT
   Equipment, EquipmentName, count(Equipment) as Count
FROM
   Operations o
   LEFT JOIN Orders ord ON  ord.Id = o.[Order]
   LEFT OUTER JOIN Equipments e ON ord.Equipment = e.EquipmentNumber
GROUP BY 
   Equipment, EquipmentName
   ORDER BY Count DESC;
```

Another Question is how i can show o.Worktime?
i got an error with GroupBy...

please help me Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this query:

```
select equip_nr,
       (select equipmentname from table_equipments where equipmentnr = [to].equip_nr) equip_name,
       sum(timeInMins) / 60.0 Worktime
from (
    select (select equipmentnr from table_orders where id = [to].[order]) equip_nr,
           case when workunittime = 'RH' then worktime * 60 else worktime end timeInMins
    from table_operations [to]
    where exists(select 1 from table_orders
                 where [to].[order] = id
                   and location = '152')
      and [start] >= '2018-07-01 00:00:00.000' and [start] < '2018-08-01 00:00:00.000'
) [to] group by equip_nr
```

By the way, `LEFT JOIN` is equivalent to `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.

Comment: Wow Thank you! And where can i add the "WHERE CLAUSE"? AND i asked it WRONG i need Minutes :-(

Comment: @silazzz You can use `WHERE` clause. Instead of `sum(timeInMins) / 60.0 Worktime` use just `sum(timeInMins) Worktime`. If my answer helped you, you should accept it and optionally upvote.

Comment: Sorry iam out of order :-( i want to add this     WHERE Orders.start >= '2018-07-01 00:00:00.000' AND Orders.[start] < '2018-08-01 00:00:00.000'

Comment: @silazzz, the Order table you defined above, only has two columns [ID] and [EquipmentNR]. you might need to expand it to include the columns [start] to help understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: oh okay thanks , but is **from Operations [to]** missing?

Comment: Well, it should be able to find it, accordingly to you presented tables.

Comment: its me again i need a little update see my Orders Table. i will only show the Orders with **Location LIKE 152**. i added in where clause but doesnt except it. how cann i access the **table_orders.Location** in Where Clause?

Comment: @silazzz see update. You might want consider using `JOIN`s for that, since your additional requirements made the query look ugly.

Comment: Thanks for your fast support! yeah a little bit ugly, but it works very well :-)

Answer (score 0):

Just use `SUM(worktime)` as aggregate function, instead of `COUNT(Equipment)`

```
SELECT
   e.[ID_Equipment]
   , Name
   , SUM( IIF(o.WorkUnitTime='MIN', worktime/60.0, worktime) ) as WorktimeMIN
FROM
   Operations o
   LEFT JOIN Orders ord ON  ord.ID_Order = o.ID_Order
   LEFT OUTER JOIN Equipment e ON ord.ID_Equipment = e.ID_Equipment
GROUP BY 
   e.[ID_Equipment]
   , Name
ORDER BY
  WorktimeMIN DESC
```

See SQL Fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/5b5ed/11